# How do you avoid frontrunning when initializing a program with a PDA?

Tags: anchor, program

Let's say I have a PDA which maintains the global state of my program. This is like a singleton. And the following snippets of code initialize it :

```
pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
    require!(
        !ctx.accounts.global.initialized,
        ErrorCodes::AlreadyInitialized
    );

    ctx.accounts.global.authority = *ctx.accounts.user.key;
    ctx.accounts.global.initialized = true;

    Ok(())
}
```

And here is the accounts struct:

```
#[account]
pub struct Global {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub initialized: bool,
    pub some_things_here: bool;
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8+1+1, seeds = [b"global"], bump)]
    pub global: Account<'info, Global>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

It is entirely possible that somebody could frontrun the initialization. For example:

1. Deploy the program
2. Attacker calls `initialize` before the honest admin can call `initialize`
3. Now the attacker has full control and is the `authority`

How can I prevent this attack (I'm using anchor)? Does there exist a best practice?

Answer (score 3):

You can for example add a check on who can call the function like so:

https://beta.solpg.io/tutorials/battle-coins

```
const ADMIN_PUBKEY: Pubkey = pubkey!("REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_WALLET_PUBKEY");
...
#[account(
    mut,
    address = ADMIN_PUBKEY
)]
pub admin: Signer<'info>,
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this programatically or do I have to manually copy+paste my key?

Comment: By programatically do it what do you mean? You're adding code to automatically manage. You can have more code that allows admin key to change as well.